# Setting checkboxes based on some value by Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to set one of the checkbox based on the value of `student.student_type` where student is json object that I get after an ajax call and `student.student_type` can be one among 0,1,2 and 3 where 0 => Regular, 1=>Correspondence and so on.

```
       <input id="student_type_" type="checkbox" value="Regular" />Regular
       <input id="student_type_" type="checkbox" value="Correspondence" />Correspondence
       <input id="student_type_" type="checkbox" value="Exchange"/>Exchange
       <input id="student_type_" type="checkbox" value="Dual" />Dual
```

As the ids of all the checkboxes in the resulting html are same, I cannot decide how to do it. Is there any way I can use the value of the checkboxes to achieve that purpose? Please help.

Comment: (a) [There is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). (b) IDs MUST be **unique**.

Comment: IDs mush be unique and try checking checkbox based on value instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs must be unique, so you should give the elements a common class instead:

```
<input class="student_type_" type="checkbox" value="Regular" />Regular
<input class="student_type_" type="checkbox" value="Correspondence" />Correspondence
<!-- ... -->
```

It seems that the position if the element correspondence to the number in the data. If that's the case, just get the right element by index:

```
$('.student_type_').eq(student.student_type).prop('checked', true);
```

If you change the order of the elements, this won't work anymore of course. You might want to use the number value as actual value of the checkbox:

```
<input class="student_type_" type="checkbox" value="0" />Regular
<!-- ... -->
```

and use the attribute selector instead:

```
$('.student_type[value="' + student.student_type + '"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Or if you cannot change the value, you can use an array for the mapping:

```
var types = ['Regular', 'Correspondence', /*...*/];
$('.student_type[value="' + types[student.student_type] + '"]').prop('checked', true);
```

---

Since a student can only be of one type, you might want to consider to use radio buttons instead of checkboxes.